# show correct category name and fix post title permalink wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I use this code to show different posts in different divs.

I have 2 problems:

1. I can't show the correct category name to current post.

   - The same category name is applied to 2 post when I use:

     ```
     get_category_link($recent['ID'])
     ```
2. Clicking on the post title redirect me to home page instead post's page!

   ```
       <div class="modulex">
           <?php
           $args = array('numberposts' => '1', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'offset' => '2');
           $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);

           foreach ($recent_posts as $recent) {?>

              <div><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($recent['ID'],'small', array('class'=>'img-fluid')); ?></div>
               <div class="spanlike"><h6><a href="<?php get_permalink($recent["ID"]) ?>"><?php echo $recent["post_title"] ?></a></h6></div>

           <?php } ?>
       </div><?php
       wp_reset_query();
       ?>
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The problem with this is that `get_category_link` requires a *category* ID as argument, not post ID. To get around this, you'll have to perform several steps:

   - retrieve a list of categories for your post
   - decide which category to use from the list (assuming you only have one category per post, just use the first/only one)
   - get the link for this category

   I would suggest using a custom function for this. Example below.
2. Here I think your problem is that `get_permalink` returns rather than echos. You could use `the permalink` instead:

   ```
   <div class="spanlike"><h6><a href="<?php the_permalink($recent["ID"]) ?>"><?php echo $recent["post_title"] ?></a></h6></div>
   ```

Example function for retrieving category link from post ID:

```
function get_cat_link_from_postID($postID) {
  $categories = get_the_category($postID);
  $catID = $categories[0]->term_id;
  return get_category_link($catID);
}
```